# php and dompdf - how to generate a large pdf without having my server come to a screeching halt

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm attempting to render a largish html table to pdf with dompdf.  There is minimal css styling, but maybe 200 - 300 rows in the table.  Each row has 4 td's with basic text.

I can generate a pdf of a smaller table with no issues but a larger table will exhaust memory limits and the script will terminate.  What is the best way to approach this?  I started a discussion on serverfault and one user suggested spawning a new process so as to not exhaust memory limits of php / apache?  Would this be the best way to do this?  That leads me to questions about how that would work, in that dompdf currently streams the download to the browser, but I'm assuming if I create a new process to generate the report, I can no longer send the output to the browser for the user to download?

Thanks to anyone who might be able to suggest a good way to tackle this!

Comment: I, too, am interested in what others have to say about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you render your HTML using a secondary PHP process (e.g. using `exec()`) the execution time and memory limits are eased. When rendering in this method you save the rendered PDF to a directory on the web site and redirect the user to the download (or even email them a link if you want to run a rendering queue). Generally I've found that this method does offer modest improvements in speed and memory use.

That doesn't, however, mean the render will perform significantly faster in your situation. Rendering tables with dompdf is resource intensive at present. What might work better, if you can, is to break the document into parts, render each of those parts separately (again using a secondary PHP process), combining the resulting collection of PDFs into a single file (using something like pdftk), then saving the PDF where the user can access it. I've seen a significant performance improvement using this method.

Or go with something like wkhtmltopdf (if you have shell access to your server and are willing to deal with the installation process).

Comment: Thanks BrianS, I'll take these into consideration.  I briefly looked at wkhtmltopdf so I'll give that another look as well.

Comment: Good luck. If you decide to stick with dompdf and need an example I can produce some code (or point to something I previously wrote) if needed.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'm going to look into spawning background processes and saving the resulting file to a directory the user can download the file from.  Maybe send an email when the report generation is complete.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: This has been discussed on the forums before, see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/tvYDvZQ6u0E/discussion. I have some (fairly old) code I wrote that renders HTML-based test packets to PDF in batch, one page at a time, combined afterwards with pdftk, see here: http://eclecticgeek.com/code/dompdf.txt

Answer (score 2):

I have had this trouble with many different generated file types, not just PDFs.  Spawning processes did not help because the problem was in the sizes of the variables, and no matter how fresh the process, the variables were still too big.  My solution was to create a file and write to it in manageable chunks, so that my variables never got above a certain size.

A basic, untested example:

```
$tmp = fopen($tmpfilepath, 'w');
if(is_resource($tmp)) {
    echo 'Generating file ... ';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $counter = 0;
    $html = '';
    while($line = getLineOfYourHtml()) {
        $html .= $line;
        $counter++;
        if($counter%200 == 0) {  //pick a good chunk number here
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            $output = $dompdf->output();
            fwrite($tmp, $output);

            echo round($counter/getTotalLines()).'%... ';  //echo percent complete

            $html = '';
        }
    }
    if($html != '') {  //the last chunk
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $output = $dompdf->output();
        fwrite($tmp, $output);
    }
    fclose($tmp);

    if(file_exists($tmpfilepath)) {
        echo '100%. Generation complete. ';
        echo '<a href="'.$tmpfileURL.'">Download</a>';
    } else {
        echo ' Generation failed.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not generate file.';
}
```

Because it takes a while to generate the file, the echoes appear one after another, giving the user something to look at so they don't think the screen has frozen.  The final echoed link will only appear after the file has been generated, which means the user is automatically waiting until the file is ready before they can download it.  You may have to extend the max execution time for this script.

Comment: Seems like i have searching for your answer only,thanks a ton.Such a creative logic, would you like to explain how can i get the getLineOfYourHtml().

Comment: @Jangyasatapathy That is just an example of how you might call your own function inside the while loop.  You are supposed to fill in the details yourself.

Comment: Everytime we load an html to dompdf it must be a proper  html format with all closing tags otherwise it is giving exception. Dompdf is not smart enough to memorize asynchronously.